# Consulta Mysql con "UNION" identificar origen de los datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT tc.idCompra, tc.fchCompra, tc.dblTotalFinal, tc.pedidoSap, 
u.nUsuario, tc.intEstado
FROM productos.tblcompra tc
INNER JOIN productos.usuario u ON tc.idUsuario=u.idUsuario
WHERE tc.intEstado=4
UNION
SELECT id, fecha_genero, total, pedido_sap, cesit, estatus
FROM normatividad.tblcompra
WHERE estatus = 4
order by nUsuario

Resultado actual
-------- --------------------------------------------
idCompra|fchCompra|total|pedidoSAP|nUsuario|intEstado
-----------------------------------------------------
123456  |xxxx-xx-x|5262 | 456321  | 2563   |   4   
123457  |xxxx-xx-x|5282 | 456921  | 2575   |   4
```

La consulta funciona bien me arroja los datos correctamente de ambas tablas de las 2 bases de datos a las que hace referencia.
La pregunta es si hay manera de identificar o agregar una columna en la consulta que me indique de que base vienen los datos.

```
 Resultado esperado
-------- ---------------------------------------------------
idCompra|fchCompra|total|pedidoSAP|nUsuario|intEstado|origen
------------------------------------------------------------
123456  |xxxx-xx-x|5262 | 456321  | 2563   |   4     | base1
123457  |xxxx-xx-x|5282 | 456921  | 2575   |   4     | base2
```

O en su defecto como identificar de que base y tabla provienen cada dato, estoy utilizando MySQL con PHP 5.6
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo agrega un string al final de cada consulta indicando cual base es:

```
SELECT tc.idCompra, tc.fchCompra, tc.dblTotalFinal, tc.pedidoSap, 
u.nUsuario, tc.intEstado, 'Base1' AS Origen
FROM productos.tblcompra tc
INNER JOIN productos.usuario u ON tc.idUsuario=u.idUsuario
WHERE tc.intEstado=4
UNION
SELECT id, fecha_genero, total, pedido_sap, cesit, estatus, 'Base2' AS Origen
FROM normatividad.tblcompra
WHERE estatus = 4
order by nUsuario
```

Answer (score 0):

complementando la respuesta de 'TheVicShow', y para mejorar la perfomance de la consulta; ya que se sabe que el comportamiento de este **UNION** va significar resultados por separado en ambos **SELECT**, cambiar a por **UNION ALL**, asi le indicas al motor que no debe realizar una verificación para devolver registros únicos.